# change event is not triggering when a select box is selected in jquery

Tags: jquery

I made a select box and tried to fetch the value of selected option using jquery.It's not working. I just alerted some text. That also not working. Need help.
id of the select box is class-in-charge.I want to add that value to input box with id tk_no.

```
    $('#class-in-charge').on('change',function(){
    //alert("hi");
    var data=$('#class-in-charge').val();
    $("#tk_no").val(data);

});
```

Comment: Your script is syntactically correct.  Can you show the markup?

Comment: Try the other way by changing your first line to `$('#class-in-charge').change(function(){` and see if it works

Comment: @Dumisani `$('#class-in-charge').on('change'` is the same as `$('#class-in-charge').change(`

Comment: I made select box with jquery(append() method) and also many functions are used here to fetch the data from database to options.It's a long code.

Comment: Use mock up html or inspect the element after it has been created.  Anyway the code above works so have a look for any other errors - https://jsfiddle.net/9dh3hf23/2/

Comment: @Dumisani I tried that too before, then also its not working

Comment: Show us your HTML too

Comment: @Sidharth Please use the site to request help.  Help provided with an off site product like Teamviewer is not trackable with Stack Overflow, and if your question is resolved like that, the solution will not be visible here, making the question useless to future visitors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yg0amssp/1/  The script runs fine.

Comment: @Taplar I teamviewed in. And it was a problem with a library. Ok. All good now.

Comment: Please detail in an answer then what the solution was, and what the true issue was.

Comment: @Taplar, done….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped with a Teamviewer session.

[The culprit was the Select2 framework.](https://select2.org/)

It changes all `classes` and `ids`.

And sets a `select2-` in front of the existing names.

Also tricky was, to find the right place to call an `ID` then.

Because after the `select2()` was called.

It takes a time to let Select2 do its work.

Means, the new `select2-` appended names were — not — immediately available.

So if you come here with that problem.

And want a really safe solution.

Add a callback function into the `select2()` function at the end.

Which triggers your then-to-do-work.

See it as dynamically.

Comment: After one hour I will send you my Id and password.Now Im not having laptop

Comment: OK, let’s do it.

Comment: ID:273 597 248    Password: 6513

Comment: OK. What is it.

Comment: ID: 273 597 248 password:4364

Comment: Does it find the `$("#selclass")`?

Comment: yes. I alerted a text when clicking on the #selclass

Comment: I do — not — see another solution either. Yours usually works. Perhaps you want to use a `class` on all radio buttons.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: No, Still its not

Comment: How to disable the radio button?. That also I'm not getting.$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selclass").prop("disabled", true);
 });

Comment: If you don't bother, can you check it with teamviewer? . I'm sorry to disturb

Comment: ID: 273 597 248 Password: 7862

Comment: No sorry. Got no time anymore. Ask the Lord deeply in you for help.

Comment: I got the problem now. Actually it is getting disabled, but I use bootstrap button for radio button. So there radio button is disabled but bootstrap button is not..

Comment: Bro, I created a dataTable. Im adding rows according to the option selected. So, when I changes option, it is not reading the entries(only first time entrie is reading), eg:Showing 1 to 10 of 23 entries). If I changes the option and clicks on manage button, rows are changed, but the no. of entries not. Need help. I have only limited time. I need to submit my project next month. How could I show my code to you?

Comment: Hi. I have no idea about `dataTables`.

Comment: I am about to sleep. Ask another question…

Comment: Hello bro, one last help. My project submission is on this week.. : – (